# Cloth simulation plus attached object

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have 2 objects. Zipper and a case. Both objects have a cloth simulation. I need to connect these objects together to animate together and create something like in the third image.

I tried to merge objects into one, vertex parent zipper and case, pin case to the zipper... But none of that worked. Maybe I tried the wrong way.

Is there a way how to get the two objects into one and achieve they correctly deform together?

[image: zipper and case]

[image: my simulation]

[image: this should final render looks like]

Comment: follow-up question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/309441/107598

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved it with MeshDeform Modifier. It is simple and effective.

I made a mesh around zipper and case and assign Cloth Simulation to it. Then I assigned MeshDeform to the zipper and the case and for Object I used the mesh with Cloth Simulation.

I followed this tutorial: [blender Quick Tips - Cloth Simulation for Animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVBOR9DdxuI)

Comment: Would you expand your solution so that people can understand the answer without the video? Because it's no longer available, the link is dead. That's why it is highly suggested here to explain the method in the answer itself and not rely on external links.