# Need help with Cloth simulation plus attached object

Tags: animation, objects, cloth-simulation, surface-deform

I have the same issue as in the question
[Cloth simulation plus attached object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106137/cloth-simulation-plus-attached-object) but the solution video mentioned is no longer available.

Can anyone please help me with how can I get the same result?
This artwork is not done by me :)
[image]

Comment: really thank you please tell me how can i attach those zippers with the cloth element, i just want to attach them like i want to bind a metal object with cloth, dont want to animate zipper. assume there are metal boxes which are binded with cloth instead of this ziiper. please help me if possible thank you.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106137/cloth-simulation-plus-attached-object

Answer (score 8):

You could create the envelop with this kind of cylinder, rip the middle edge with <kbd>V</kbd>, select all its vertices and assign to a group that will be its cloth pin group:

[image]

Give it the following modifiers: *Vertex Weight Proximity, Cloth, Weld, Solidify, Subdivision*. Create a cylinder that will be your tire, give it a *Collision* physic, create an object (cube) that will be it *Vertex Weight Proximity* object and will allow you to move the evenlop pin group, create a *Force Field* that will push apart the 2 sides of the envelop:

[image]

Result when you move the *Vertex Weight Proximity* object:

[image]

Other solution: Create 2 plane objects, subdivide a bit, give them cloth simulations with a pin group that goes from bottom to top, create the tyre envelop, rip the center edge, assign a vertex group to the left half, another vertex group to the right hand half, give it 2 *Surface Deform* modifiers with the 2 planes as *Target*, each time choose the correct vertex group, click on the *Bind* buttons:

[image]

Create a *Force Field* between the 2 planes, result:

[image]

File with the 2 solutions here: [image]

Comment: looks great! +1

Comment: thank you  ;) .........

Comment: Great wheel model ;-) (I would have done it the same way) and great animation. But the main reason for this question was the zipper, wasn't it? My understanding of the problem is that the Cloth simulation does not work with two objects, the zipper and the case. The solution in the linked question therefore refers to the mesh deform modifier.

Comment: @Blunder OK I've edited, maybe this is the way he did it?

Comment: Awesome! (I just miss the tire ;-))

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: please if possible tell me ho can i attach those zippers with the cloth simulation

Comment: it should be part of the object but the problem is that it is supposed to be a bit rigid, it can't fold like the cloth, so maybe you need to tweak the cloth parameters in order to make it a bit more rigid, or use the second solution which is probably the one that has been used in your image (we can see that the folds are not real, they are just normal map), as for the little slide object you could animate it manually so that it follows the correct position

Answer (score 0):

For a similar image, it would probably be faster and easier to use the Cloth Brush in sculpting mode.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UskiTAah1-w

Alternatively, you could manually "paint" the wrinkles with a regular sculpt brush, add a winkle texture (like something from [here](https://blendermarket.com/products/blender-fabric-brushes)), and set it to "anchor" mode

Comment: i would assume he wants the animation, not an image....