# How to animate scissor cutting pipe?

Tags: animation

I want to re-create the following animation in which the Scissors cut the lymph nodes and it lands naturally.  [image]. Please suggest steps to do it.

Comment: have you tried with shapekeys?

Comment: maybe so (without the zipper, of course): https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/309441/107598

Comment: Thank you the link helps

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cylinder, rip an edge loop with <kbd>V</kbd>, give it a *Weld* modifier so that the 2 parts stick to each other, a *Solidify* to give it inner thickness, a *Bevel* to sharpen the edge and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Then create 2 shapekeyes, and for the second one, create the cut version of the object. You'll just need to keyframe the *Value* to animate:

[image]

Comment: Thank you , I will try it out